# Change TabItem Icon color dynamically based on IsSelected True/False

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, tabitem

I have Icon = Canvas (History_icon) in ResourceDictionary (Controls.xaml):

Controls.xaml:

```
<!--TABITEM STYLE-->
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="SidebarTabBackgroundBrushSelected" Color="Transparent"></SolidColorBrush>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="SidebarTabBorderBrushSelected" Color="Transparent"></SolidColorBrush>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="SidebarTabBackgroundBrush" Color="Transparent"></SolidColorBrush>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="SidebarTabBorderBrush" Color="Transparent"></SolidColorBrush>

<!--ICON COLORS-->
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="IsSelectedIcon" Color="#00ff00"></SolidColorBrush>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="IsNOTSelectedIcon" Color="#ff0000"></SolidColorBrush>

<Style x:Key="SideBarTabItem" TargetType="TabItem">
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="10,15,10,15" />
    <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="60"/>
    <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="110"/>
    <Setter Property="Foreground"  Value="Gray"></Setter>
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="12"/>
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{StaticResource Roboto}"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
                <Border Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" 
            Name="tab" 
            BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" 
            BorderBrush="{StaticResource SidebarTabBorderBrush}"
            SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                    <ContentPresenter Name="content"
                                          ContentSource="Header" />
                </Border>

                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                        <Setter TargetName="tab" Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource SidebarTabBackgroundBrushSelected}" />
                        <Setter TargetName="tab" Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource SidebarTabBorderBrushSelected}" />
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="False">
                        <Setter TargetName="tab" Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource SidebarTabBackgroundBrush}" />
                        <Setter TargetName="tab" Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource SidebarTabBorderBrush}" />
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>

            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"></Setter>
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="12"/>
            <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{StaticResource Roboto}"/>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>

<!--HISTORY-->

<Style TargetType="{x:Type ContentControl}" x:Key="History_icon">
    <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
        <Setter.Value>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Viewbox Width="{Binding Width, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ContentControl}}">
                    <Canvas Width="384.000" Height="384.000">
                        <Canvas>
                            <Canvas>
                                <!-- Layer 1/<Group>/<Compound Path> -->
                                <Path Fill="Transparent" Data="...Here are a lot of symbols, so they are shortened..."/>
                                <!-- Layer 1/<Group>/<Path> -->
                                <Path Fill="#ff000000" Data="...Here are a lot of symbols, so they are shortened..."/>
                                <!-- Layer 1/<Group>/<Path> -->
                                <Path Fill="#ff000000" Data="...Here are a lot of symbols, so they are shortened..."/>
                            </Canvas>
                        </Canvas>
                    </Canvas>
                </Viewbox>
            </DataTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

I would like to apply different color for `TabItem` `IsSelected` - `True/False`. So to be able to change this `Fill="#ff000000"` to for example Green and Red. How I can do that in my current setup?

Here is MainWindow.xaml:

```
        <TabControl HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="657" Margin="0,80,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="1072" 
                    TabStripPlacement="Left" Background="Transparent" BorderThickness="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
            <TabItem Style="{DynamicResource SideBarTabItem}">
                <TabItem.Header>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                        <ContentControl Style="{StaticResource History_icon}" Width="26" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                        <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" Padding="0,10,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Center"><Run Text="HOME"/></TextBlock>
                    </StackPanel>
                </TabItem.Header>
            </TabItem>

        </TabControl>
```

---

EDIT:

Based on answer provided:

```
<!--ICON COLORS-->
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="IsSelectedIcon" Color="Red"></SolidColorBrush>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="IsNOTSelectedIcon" Color="Green"></SolidColorBrush>

<Style TargetType="{x:Type ContentControl}" x:Key="Clock_icon">
    <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
        <Setter.Value>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Viewbox Width="{Binding Width, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ContentControl}}">
                    <Canvas Width="382.987" Height="383.051">
                        <Canvas>
                            <Canvas>
                                <!-- Layer 1/<Group>/<Compound Path> -->
                                <Path Data="F1 M 191.097,355.685 C 281.557,355.658 354.804,282.447 354.968,191.891 C 355.133,101.553 281.724,28.129 191.195,28.082 C 100.718,28.035 27.448,101.271 27.365,191.835 C 27.282,282.275 100.667,355.712 191.097,355.685 Z M 0.000,203.085 C 0.000,195.617 0.000,188.150 0.000,180.683 C 0.217,179.610 0.558,178.545 0.633,177.462 C 2.495,150.785 9.407,125.428 22.489,102.162 C 57.697,39.549 111.384,5.374 183.137,1.044 C 220.809,-1.229 256.394,7.800 288.569,27.653 C 346.580,63.448 377.962,115.797 382.038,183.849 C 384.103,218.333 376.567,251.213 359.895,281.529 C 330.245,335.448 285.004,368.398 224.478,380.033 C 217.184,381.436 209.742,382.064 202.368,383.051 C 194.901,383.051 187.433,383.051 179.966,383.051 C 179.005,382.840 178.053,382.502 177.082,382.438 C 153.622,380.896 131.120,375.296 110.077,364.923 C 51.444,336.020 15.559,289.432 3.014,225.150 C 1.595,217.876 0.985,210.444 0.000,203.085 Z">
                                    <Path.Style>
                                        <Style TargetType="Path">
                                            <Style.Triggers>
                                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=TabItem}}" Value="True">
                                                    <Setter Property="Fill" Value="{StaticResource IsSelectedIcon}" />
                                                </DataTrigger>
                                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=TabItem}}" Value="False">
                                                    <Setter Property="Fill" Value="{StaticResource IsNOTSelectedIcon}" />
                                                </DataTrigger>
                                            </Style.Triggers>
                                        </Style>
                                    </Path.Style>
                                </Path>
                                <!-- Layer 1/<Group>/<Path> -->
                                <Path Data="F1 M 202.368,383.051 C 209.742,382.064 217.184,381.436 224.478,380.033 C 285.004,368.398 330.245,335.448 359.895,281.529 C 376.567,251.213 384.103,218.333 382.038,183.849 C 377.962,115.797 346.580,63.448 288.569,27.653 C 256.394,7.800 220.809,-1.229 183.137,1.044 C 111.384,5.374 57.697,39.549 22.489,102.162 C 9.407,125.428 2.495,150.785 0.633,177.462 C 0.558,178.545 0.217,179.610 0.000,180.683 C 0.000,120.465 0.000,60.247 0.000,0.000 C 127.631,0.000 255.263,0.000 382.987,0.000 C 382.987,127.664 382.987,255.357 382.987,383.051 C 322.803,383.051 262.585,383.051 202.368,383.051 Z">
                                    <Path.Style>
                                        <Style TargetType="Path">
                                            <Style.Triggers>
                                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=TabItem}}" Value="True">
                                                    <Setter Property="Fill" Value="{StaticResource IsSelectedIcon}" />
                                                </DataTrigger>
                                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=TabItem}}" Value="False">
                                                    <Setter Property="Fill" Value="{StaticResource IsNOTSelectedIcon}" />
                                                </DataTrigger>
                                            </Style.Triggers>
                                        </Style>
                                    </Path.Style>
                                </Path>
                                <!-- Layer 1/<Group>/<Path> -->
                                <Path Data="F1 M 0.000,203.085 C 0.985,210.444 1.595,217.876 3.014,225.150 C 15.559,289.432 51.444,336.020 110.077,364.923 C 131.120,375.296 153.622,380.896 177.082,382.438 C 178.053,382.502 179.005,382.840 179.966,383.051 C 119.977,383.051 59.989,383.051 0.000,383.051 C 0.000,323.062 0.000,263.073 0.000,203.085 Z">
                                    <Path.Style>
                                        <Style TargetType="Path">
                                            <Style.Triggers>
                                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=TabItem}}" Value="True">
                                                    <Setter Property="Fill" Value="{StaticResource IsSelectedIcon}" />
                                                </DataTrigger>
                                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=TabItem}}" Value="False">
                                                    <Setter Property="Fill" Value="{StaticResource IsNOTSelectedIcon}" />
                                                </DataTrigger>
                                            </Style.Triggers>
                                        </Style>
                                    </Path.Style>
                                </Path>
                                <!-- Layer 1/<Group>/<Compound Path> -->
                                <Path Data="F1 M 177.579,178.295 C 175.458,178.295 173.977,178.295 172.495,178.295 C 142.627,178.297 112.758,178.261 82.890,178.322 C 74.243,178.339 68.295,184.050 68.345,191.955 C 68.395,199.746 74.247,205.425 82.660,205.440 C 118.626,205.503 154.593,205.536 190.559,205.339 C 193.573,205.323 196.930,204.069 199.509,202.421 C 203.858,199.642 204.798,194.976 204.789,189.973 C 204.725,154.878 204.756,119.783 204.750,84.687 C 204.750,83.568 204.737,82.445 204.642,81.331 C 204.116,75.142 199.407,70.161 193.283,69.280 C 184.386,68.000 177.621,74.146 177.602,83.790 C 177.544,113.658 177.579,143.527 177.579,173.395 C 177.579,174.859 177.579,176.324 177.579,178.295 Z M 191.097,355.685 C 100.667,355.712 27.282,282.275 27.365,191.835 C 27.448,101.271 100.718,28.035 191.195,28.082 C 281.724,28.129 355.133,101.553 354.968,191.891 C 354.804,282.447 281.557,355.658 191.097,355.685 Z">
                                    <Path.Style>
                                        <Style TargetType="Path">
                                            <Style.Triggers>
                                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=TabItem}}" Value="True">
                                                    <Setter Property="Fill" Value="{StaticResource IsSelectedIcon}" />
                                                </DataTrigger>
                                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=TabItem}}" Value="False">
                                                    <Setter Property="Fill" Value="{StaticResource IsNOTSelectedIcon}" />
                                                </DataTrigger>
                                            </Style.Triggers>
                                        </Style>
                                    </Path.Style>
                                </Path>
                                <!-- Layer 1/<Group>/<Path> -->
                                <Path Data="F1 M 177.579,178.295 C 177.579,176.324 177.579,174.859 177.579,173.395 C 177.579,143.527 177.544,113.658 177.602,83.790 C 177.621,74.146 184.386,68.000 193.283,69.280 C 199.407,70.161 204.116,75.142 204.642,81.331 C 204.737,82.445 204.750,83.568 204.750,84.687 C 204.756,119.783 204.725,154.878 204.789,189.973 C 204.798,194.976 203.858,199.642 199.509,202.421 C 196.930,204.069 193.573,205.323 190.559,205.339 C 154.593,205.536 118.626,205.503 82.660,205.440 C 74.247,205.425 68.395,199.746 68.345,191.955 C 68.295,184.050 74.243,178.339 82.890,178.322 C 112.758,178.261 142.627,178.297 172.495,178.295 C 173.977,178.295 175.458,178.295 177.579,178.295 Z">
                                    <Path.Style>
                                        <Style TargetType="Path">
                                            <Style.Triggers>
                                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=TabItem}}" Value="True">
                                                    <Setter Property="Fill" Value="{StaticResource IsSelectedIcon}" />
                                                </DataTrigger>
                                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=TabItem}}" Value="False">
                                                    <Setter Property="Fill" Value="{StaticResource IsNOTSelectedIcon}" />
                                                </DataTrigger>
                                            </Style.Triggers>
                                        </Style>
                                    </Path.Style>
                                </Path>
                            </Canvas>
                        </Canvas>
                    </Canvas>
                </Viewbox>
            </DataTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

I am getting this:

[image]

You can see clock, but it is behind red background. What I am still doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the Fill in a Path style using a DataTrigger. The DataTrigger must target the ancestor type (TabItem) IsSelected property, and the Path needs to have the Fill taken off (or it will override the DataTrigger value).

```
<Path Data="M 10,100 C 10,300 300,-200 300,100">
    <Path.Style>
        <Style TargetType="Path">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=TabItem}}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Fill" Value="{StaticResource IsSelectedIcon}" />
                 </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=TabItem}}" Value="False">
                    <Setter Property="Fill" Value="{StaticResource IsNOTSelectedIcon}" />
                 </DataTrigger>
             </Style.Triggers>
         </Style>
     </Path.Style>
</Path>
```

Obviously you can move this out into a reusable style somewhere but this is all I added to get it working.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I am  having some issues still, can you guide a little bit further what I am still doing wrong?  Your example works as expected, however after implementing it in my case it is not acting as expected.

Comment: I've tried this with different combinations of the paths switched off; if you turn off the fourth path you get a coloured square with a plain white circle, and coloured clock hands. Is that what you're expecting?

Comment: For a white background and coloured icon (circle+clock hands), only the first and last paths need to be coloured (other paths can be removed).

Comment: Ah, my bad, maybe it is too much letters and numbers for today. Actually 2, 3 and 4 should be transparent. For 1 and 5 your suggested logic should be applied. Now I am a little bit wiser in XAML once again. Thank you!

Comment: Yes, as I have just figured out what you have stated in your last comment